# OpenCV matrix from vector of vectors without copying the data

Tags: c++, opencv

Is it possible to create `cv::Mat` from `std::vector<std::vector<T>>`, where all the vectors are the same width, without copying the data, i.e. creating just header, as it could be for creating `cv::Mat` from `std::vector<T>`?

I have a wrapper that can use only STL types in interface and passes them to underlying OpenCV functions. I would like to avoid excessive transformations back and forth.

Comment: despite the answer below, it is possible....with a little "cheat"

Answer (score 3):

In general, no.  You cannot make any guarantees about the relative memory locations of each inner std::vector.  A cv::Mat needs all of its memory to be continuous or have a predictable jump between each row.  It only stores one pointer to the beginning of its data and accessing your inner vector requires a pointer for each vector.

If you can somehow guarantee that your memory is continuous then yes you can.

Answer (score 1):

If what you are really looking for is efficiency, you should work based on using this constructor:

```
// C++: 

Mat::Mat(int rows, int cols, int type, void* data, size_t step=AUTO_STEP)¶
```

This constructor does not copy the data, which is where any inefficiency is likely to lie. 
Therefore instead of having nested vectors, have a single vector that contains all the data.

Note that the lifetime of the data in your vector must be sufficient for access to the matrix, and that means you also cannot modify the size of your vector as this could invalidate the underlying data which is `&v[0]`.

If you're allowed to use `boost::matrix` in your general code it may well solve your problem.